# How do I replace the deprecated methods toSuccessCallbackString and writeJavascript in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

Since I am coming from a Java background I am not an Objective-C expert and thus struggling a bit to modify the following code:

```
- (void) loadHTML:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

    NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSArray *arguments = command.arguments;

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult;

    if (webView)
    {
        NSString *stringObtainedFromJavascript = [arguments objectAtIndex:0]; 
        [webView loadHTMLString:stringObtainedFromJavascript baseURL:baseURL];

        if (screenNeedsInit) {
            [self makeScreenVisible];
        }

        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString: WEBVIEW_OK];
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
    }
    else
    {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString: WEBVIEW_UNAVAILABLE];        
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:callbackId]];    
    }

}
```

The compiler complains that both, `writeJavascript` as well as `toErrorCallbackString` are deprecated and I should replace them with `evalJS` and `pluginResult`.

So, my first step was to change this line:

```
[self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
```

like this:

```
[self.commandDelegate evalJs: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
```

So, this worked, but I still need to replace `toSuccessCallbackString` with `sendPluginResult`, so I googled up this:

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
```

But how do I combine `evalJS` with `sendPluginResult` now? In the old version it seemed to me that `pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString` simply returned a `NSString*` but now with `sendPluginResult` there seems to be a callback involved? How do I manage this to pass the result of `sendPluginResult` to `evalJS`.

Note: I am using the cordova api for this.

Please be gentle, I didn't write much Objective-C yet and I struggle with the syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
```

if you used `CDVCommandStatus_OK` on the pluginResult, then it will call the success callback, if you used `CDVCommandStatus_ERROR` then it will call the error callback

Your javascript should be something like this:

```
cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "YourPluginName", "loadHTML",["yourHtmlString"]);
```

Comment: What is the callback method where I can call [self.commandDelegate evalJs:javascriptString]; I have replaced [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:command.callbackId] to [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId]; But in which method will I get the Javascript String to call evalJs method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question was about how to replace the deprecated `writeJavascript` and the answer is to use `sendPluginResult` for the question use case. If you want to use evalJs then your use case might be different. Can you create a new question providing more information?

Comment: Oh oki.. I tgt sendPluginResult is to replace toErrorCallbackId and toSuccessCallbackId and writeJavascript method should be replaced by evalJs method.. If sendPluginResult does the job, then that's what I needed.. please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `sendPluginResult` uses `evalJS` internally. If your plugin finish the execution and you want to send the result or error to your app (execute the callback with the data) then use `sendPluginResult`, if you want the native part of the plugin to execute some javascript, then use `evalJS`